# How to execute the .exe only by the cmd

Tags: c#, cmd

I have a program c#, that program has a .exe like every programs,i need to be able to open,and so execute that .exe only by writing in the command prompt the command "/edit nameOfTheProgram". It has to be a substitute of a login  popup.Is it possible?

Comment: i have not understand what you mean by /edit nameOfTheProgram , or  you want just to run your program from cmd ?

Comment: You can run your .exe from the cmd by navigating to the directory it's stored in and typing `nameOfTheProgram` . The cmd will then execute the program. Is this what you are wanting? `/edit` is not a standard cmd command

Comment: @Symon that's the point i've to create somehow a command that followed by the name of the program.exe execute it "/edit program.exe" and only if i write that line i can execute the .exe of that program if not i'm not able to run it

Comment: Are you basically wanting an EXE that can only be launched if a special command is used? So, if I navigated to it and double clicked it, it would simply start and exit because a condition was not met?

Comment: kind of, it i navigate to it i'm not able to open it

Comment: Sounds like you want to add an argument to your program, and if the argument doesn't match the right phrase/characters then exit?

Comment: mh could work, i need to write /edit program and that's the only way to execute it

Comment: It's an EXE, you can't stop the execution without setting security in the system; that would be the secure method, but unless you are in a corporate network environment, something that can't really be leveraged. The only thing you can do is verify a special code is passed in that allows it to do more than just exit. This is not secure in the least by the way

Comment: so it isn't possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the path of your .Exe, in "Path" of enviroment variables.

Comment: explain please maybe i've misunderstood

Comment: Try this: 1) Right click of "Computer" Icon; 2) Properties;  3) Advanced setting;  4) Enviroment Variables.    5)  Add path of your exe without exe in "Path" enviroment variable.

Comment: ok done it but it doesn't solve the problem, it has to be Exclusive, the only way to open it

Comment: If in your application you add logins and passwords as system args to control privileges?

Comment: for example in cmd windows:      yourApplication.exe   login: user    pass: 1234

Comment: can't, the request is clear and not fruit of my mind. /edit program has to be the only way to execute the program.exe

Comment: You can control if there is the pront windows. If true, run the application else close it.

Comment: what do you mean for "pront"

Comment: pront is cmd windows.